# Sliding up and showing hidden element twice in same page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi can anyone help me to figure out the way how can I achieve the below mentioned effect. I have top banner section, a button in the bottom of the banner, when i click the button, form should open with sliding up effect. Initially form will be hidden. And I need the same effect in the bottom of the page as well. When i click on contact us button form should slide up.[image]

[image]

Here is the link which i m trying
http://jsbin.com/liyimo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Just add the button and update the function:

```
  <button class="btn cta-button btn2" id="cta-contact">Contact us</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cta-button").click(function(){
        $(".arrow-up, .engage-form-section").slideDown("slow");
    });
  $(".close").click(function(){
        $(".arrow-up, .engage-form-section").slideUp("slow");
    });
  $(".btn2").click(function(){
        $(".arrow-up, .engage-form-section").slideUp("slow");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/msuooay7/2/

Comment: You can combine 2 events into one like `$(".close,.btn2").click(function(){` as they are performing the same thing..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Thank you for this suggestion! You are right.

Comment: Hey thanks Madalina Taina, I want to slide it up as well, i m just trying to use animate({bottom: '250px'}) property, but wat is the best way to slide it up in all responsive screens.

Comment: My updated jsbin http://jsbin.com/jizuja/edit?html,css,js,output when i click single button, form opens twice.

Comment: You need the form slideDown at click on "contact us" button?

Comment: Your description: "When i click on contact us button form should slide up"

Comment: Yes it should slide down and move up.